# How to change dyno process?

Tags: ubuntu, heroku

I'm working through this tutorial (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python) for learning how to use Heroku. Here's my issue:

1) Worked through the typical stuff for deploying an app:

```
$ heroku create
$ git push heroku master
$ heroku ps:scale web=1
$ heroku ps
```

The process are:

```
== web (1X): 'gunicorn hello:app'
```

The Procfile has the text "web: gunicorn hello:app". Files/directories in folder "svm":

```
svm
--hello.py
--hello.pyc
--Procfile
--requirements.txt
--svm.py
--svm.pyc
--venv
```

2) Now, I've created a new python file, say svm.py, in that same folder. I've changed the procfile from "web: gunicorn hello:app" to "web: gunicorn svm:app"

```
$ git add .
$ git push heroku master
$ heroku ps:scale web=0
$ heroku ps:scale web=1
$ heroku ps
```

But for some reason, I still get:

```
=== web (1X): 'gunicorn hello:app'
```

How can I change this to reflect the fact that I want to use svm.py now, instead of hello.py?

Comment: Did you `git commit` after `git add`?

Answer (score 0):

@Nitzan Your answer worked well, and furthermore, as it turns out I also had to supplement my heroku build with the details outlined in here: [Deploy matplotlib on heroku failed. How to do this correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173104/deploy-matplotlib-on-heroku-failed-how-to-do-this-correctly)